# How do I iteratively add to a List on button click in java?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to add values to an array/list and then store these in shared preferences, to then display on another activity.

When I try my code it only seems to save the first value, and if I add more it just overwrites the value.

I do not want to create the List each time I click the button so I have put it at the very beginning.

If there isn't an existing value then the message should be added to the List and stored in shared preferences as Status_0, if there is an existing value then it should be added as Status_1 - but it's not. I think it is because it is not saving properly in the List but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here's my code:

```
public class EnterReadingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener {
private EditText erTemperatureEditText;
private Button erSubmitBtn;
public List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enterreadings);
    init();

}

private void init() {
    erTemperatureEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.erTemperatureEditText);
    erSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.erSubmitBtn);
    erSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId()==R.id.erSubmitBtn) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        String message = erTemperatureEditText.getText().toString();

        editor.putInt("Status_size", values.size());
        int status_size = values.size();

        for (int i = status_size; i < status_size + 1; i++) {
            editor.putString("Status_" + i, message);
            values.add(message);
            editor.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
int status_size = values.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < status_size + 1; i++)
    {
        String value = values.get(i);
        if (value != null) {
            values.add(value);
            status_size++;

            String textView_i = "textView" + i;
            TextView textView_i = new TextView(this);
            textView_i.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView_i.setText(value);
            historyBackgroundInside.addView(textView_i);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Someone just gave a constructive comment but now it's gone.. this was my reply:   Thanks a lot, the list should be empty to start with as there are no values - and I thought I was adding to the list with "values.add(message);" inside the for loop. And it was status_size+1 because if there are 2 entries in the list then i = 2, and it will run on the first go, then it will stop because of the i++.

Comment: You are adding it to an `ArrayList` but where/how are you trying to display it? You should be using some type of `Adapter` (assuming you are wanting to show it in a `ListView` and call `adapterName.notifyDatasetChanged()` when you update the underlying list.

Comment: In my next activity I would create a textview for each record and display the value - that is if I can pass it to shared preferences

Comment: @codeMagic In my next activity I would create a textview for each record and display the value - that is if I can pass it to shared preferences (not sure if you get the notification without the tag :) )

Comment: I would since I'm the only one commenting so far but you can also edit comments for a short period of time. Anyway, with `editor.putString("Status_" + i, message);` you are always overwriting what's in there.

Comment: Understood, the idea is that 'i' would equal the ArrayList length and since the ArrayList starts at 0 then "Status_" + i should be 'Status_0' the first time, and then 'Status_1' the next time so it doesn't overwrite. Is this because it's not adding the the ArrayList properly? So int status_size = values.size(); is always 0? If so do you have any idea how I make it add to the ArrayList properly?

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to use the sharedPreferences to pass data from one activity to another.
The data are usually entered into an object (Bundle) which will be passed in the intent and then taken up in the next activity.

another way is to use the extras that works like Bundle

```
public class EnterReadingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText erTemperatureEditText;
    private Button erSubmitBtn;
    public List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enterreadings);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        erTemperatureEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.erTemperatureEditText);
        erSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.erSubmitBtn);
        erSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
           if (view.getId()==R.id.erSubmitBtn) {
               String message = erTemperatureEditText.getText().toString();
               values.add(message);
           }

           //Here you should enter the condition that allows you to
           //call the method to go to the next activity 
           //ex: click of a button, I have the list reaches a size
           //Add a example code
           if (values.size() == 10) {
               passDataAndGoInAnotherActivity();
           }
    }

    public void passDataAndGoInAnotherActivity () {
         Intent i = new Intent (this, NameOfYouNextActivity.class);

         i.putExtra("status_list", values);
         // Or use Bundle
         // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         // bundle.putSerializable("status_list", values);
         // i.putExtra("bundle", values)
         startActivity(i)
     }
}
```

to take in the other activity values using this code

```
 public class NameOfYourNextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     public List<String> values;
     public ListView listView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_nameoflayout);

         listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

         Intent intent = getIntent();

         //If you first method
         if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("status_list")) {
              List<String> values = (List<String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("status_list")
         }
         //If you second method (Bundle)
         // if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("Bundle")) {
         // Bundle bundle = intent. getBundleExtra("Bundle")
         // if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("status_list")) {
         // List<String> values = (List<String>)intent.getSerializableExtra(String name)
         // }

         if (values != null) {
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
             listview.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
       }
    }
```

I did the update of the code to give you a solution that comes close to what you need..

Remember to create the next activity and insert it in the manifest.

Change the name of the class based on your activity and enter the correct layout name.

Remember to include in your layout a list view (change id in my code) that will allow you to print your values.

In this example it uses a simple adapter with a layout provided by Android, but you can create something custom.

Here you will find an excellent [guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: *"It is incorrect to use the sharedPreferences to pass data from one activity to another. "* no, that is not correct. Depending on the need for that data, `SharedPreferences` can be used. Yes, sometimes a bundle makes more sense but to say it is incorrect to use `SharedPreferences` here is...incorrect and I don't believe this actually solves the problem in any way.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely usable and my answer is unclear and incorrect. But useSharedPreferences to pass a list of values of an indefinite quantity (0 to infinity), it becomes a dirty practice.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea in this case but to say that it is incorrect in general is not necessarily true.

Comment: Hey it may not be best practice, but if you know how to do it with my code  would you be able to share? If I got it working and understood it id be in a better position to refactor it and follow best practice

Comment: In the code you shared not see the operation that allows you to move to the next activity. It would help if you put all the code of this activity and the next  activity, in order to understand the flow is give you a fix or give you the code to add

Comment: I don't have the code for the next activity because I can't get the data to store properly in the array/list or shared preferences. Because each next entry overwrites the last one